# Computing the conditional column mean of a 2D numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, 2d, mean

I'm new in Python.
I have a 2D np.array (ex. 50 rows and 12 columns) and I need the mean of the 3rd column when the 1st column==x and the 9th column==y.
I can't figure out how to do it without using ifs...

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hi @sotiriadou, could you please post the code you've been trying together with some sample input data?

Comment: Although not quite a duplicate, the crux of this question is about conditional indexing in Numpy, which is addressed here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33168775/conditional-indexing-with-numpy-ndarray.

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume your array is called `arr`. In this case, you want to apply two different filters first `1st column==x` the second `9th column==y`. To begin with, you should create each filter (mask) separately and then see what you want to do with them in terms of logical relation between them and your expected output.

```
mask1 = arr[:, 0] == x  # 1st column==x
mask1 = arr[:, 8] == y  # 9th column==y
```

Now you can use `or`, `and`, or any other logical operator to create your final mask which in this case it's `and`. For that sake in numpy you can use logical functions.

```
final_mask = np.logical_and(mask1, mask2)
```

And finally all you need is to filter your array based on the `final_mask` and perform the calculations you intended to do:

```
filtered_3rd_column = arr[:, final_mask]
_mean = filtered_3rd_column.mean()
```

Comment: I can't understand where you get the 3rd column. Maybe it should be:

Comment: _mean=filtered_3rd_column[:,2].mean

Comment: Be patient. Shouldn't  be:        _mean=filtered_3rd_column[:,2].mean()

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`np.where()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
x = 1
y = 2
a[np.where((a[:, 0] == x) & (a[:, 8] == y)), 3].mean()
```

Comment: The index should be 0 and not one. :) to retrieve column one.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem as follows (thanks to Kasrâmvd):

```
mask1 = arr[:, 0] == x  # 1st column==x
mask1 = arr[:, 8] == y  # 9th column==y

final_mask = np.logical_and(mask1, mask2)

filtered_arr = arr[final_mask,:]
mean_3rd_column = filtered_arr[:,2].mean()
```