# Slicing a numpy array to select rows with values in a list. Truth value error

Tags: python, list, numpy, slice

I have a 2D numpy array, and I wish to select rows that have a specific value in a given column. This is simple enough to do with single numbers or multiple numbers, but I cannot do it for a list. Code is below, with what I have gotten to work, and my attempt at using a list:

```
matrix = np.ndarray([4, 5])
matrix[0,:] = range(1,6)
matrix[1,:] = range(6,11)
matrix[2,:] = range(11,16)
matrix[3,:] = range(16,21)

li=[9,19]

matrix2=matrix[matrix[:,3]==9] # this gives me one of the requirements.
print(matrix2)
matrix3=matrix[(matrix[:,3]==9) | (matrix[:,3]==19)] # Multiple requirements explicitly laid out works.
print(matrix3)
matrix4=matrix[matrix[:,3] in li] # multiple requirements in list form do not work.
print(matrix4)
```

I've also looked at using the np.where() command as suggested in [Conditional indexing with Numpy ndarray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33168775/conditional-indexing-with-numpy-ndarray), but this does not appear to help me, nor does it seem to change the results when it is used instead of the slicing I used above.

The specific error message I get is:

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

But I do not understand how the a.any() or a.all() commands will help me.

Comment: does `matrix4=matrix[np.isin(matrix[:,3], li)]` work?

Comment: Yes, perfect. I knew there had to be a simple solution!

@Mstaino, Post it as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: Posted. Glad it worked. I added the docs for `np.isin` for reference

Comment: The ambiguity error is raised when a test produces a boolean array in a context that expects a scalar boolean (simple True or False).  `all/any` will reduce the array down to a single value, but often isn't the solution.  Here the error is inside the `in` expression.  Your `matrix3` is good example using boolean arrays correctly.

Comment: `isin` uses `in1d`.  In some cases `in1d` uses a generalized version of your `matrix3` solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `np.isin` ([docs here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.isin.html))

```
matrix4=matrix[np.isin(matrix[:,3], li)]
```